# how to inject specific datasource in grails 3

Tags: grails

I am trying to follow the guide outlined in this URI: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources

My application.yml file, contains the following description for datasources:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
    raw:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        username: rip
        password: password
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:345:coolio

environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: create-drop
                url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE
    test:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE
    production:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:mem:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE
```

In my DatabaseService, I have the following code to try and inject the dataSource bean:

```
class DatabaseService {

    static datasource = 'raw'
    DataSource dataSource

    public void testMyDb(User user) {
        try {
            println("we are in here with : " +    dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL())
            registerUser(new Sql(dataSource), user)
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("unable to register the user", e)
            throw e
        }
    }

    public void registerDeveloper(Sql sql, User user) {
            sql.call("{call isertUser(?)}", [user.name])
    }
```

The print statement in the DatabaseService file prints out:

```
    we are in here with : jdbc:h2:mem:testDb
```

However, it should print out:

```
    we are in here with : jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:345:coolio
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it that the original Datasource bean is the one that gets instantiated?

UPDATED ATTEMPTS (1): I see a good thread here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9690 , but even after replacing

```
 static datasource = 'raw'
```

with

```
 @Autowired 
 @Qualifier('dataSource_raw')
```

nothing changes. If I grab the Springs ApplicationContext, and print out the beans, dataSource_raw is indeed one of them.

UPDATED ATTEMPTS (2): I have tried to remove the entire environment section, with nothing changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

This seems to be a bug with grails 3. Not sure if it has been fixed in newer versions (>3.0.11). Even if we specify bean name with `@Autowired and @Qualifier` annotation, grails injects the default bean in case of `dataSource, transactionManager and sessionFactory`. This could be the case with other beans also, but I have tested only these three. I haven't tested the behaviour with domains or controllers.

To overcome this, what you can do is, instead of using these default names, use custom name along with `@Autowired and @Qualifier` or `@Resource` annotation.

With following way, you will get beans for default data source, even if you are specifying to use a different bean:

```
@Resource(name = "dataSource_raw")
DataSource dataSource

@Resource(name = "transactionManager_raw")
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager

@Resource(name = "sessionFactory_raw")
SessionFactory sessionFactory
```

But with custom names, the bean with the name specified using `@Qualifier` or `@Resource` will be injected:

```
@Resource(name = "dataSource_raw")
DataSource rawDataSource

@Resource(name = "transactionManager_raw")
PlatformTransactionManager rawTransactionManager

@Resource(name = "sessionFactory_raw")
SessionFactory rawSessionFactory
```

Comment: Also note that you can still have a `application.groovy` along side the `application.yml` if you don't want to have to worry about whitespace.

Comment: the formatting was wrong in my question, i just updated that now. However, that did not solve the problem. Am I calling the datasource correctly in the service? In case I am doing it wrong, I only want the datasource of 'raw' to be in there.

Comment: that solved the problem on selecting the injected bean. Thanks for the code :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare as follows

```
def dataSource_raw
```

Without `@Resource` annotation